# tensorflow cross entropy loss for sequence with different lengths

Tags: tensorflow

i'm building a seq2seq model with LSTM using tensorflow. The loss function i'm using is the softmax cross entropy loss. The problem is my input sequences have different lenghts so i padded it. The output of the model have the shape `[max_length, batch_size, vocab_size]`. How can i calculate the loss that the 0 padded values don't affect the loss? tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits provide axis parameter so we can calculate the loss with 3-dimention but it doesn't provide weights. tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy provides weights parameter but it recieves input with shape `[batch_size, nclass(vocab_size)]`. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to write your own loss function. Check out https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i read this in the blog: "'Actually, we wouldn’t have to do the masking for the cost and error functions because both prediction and target are zero vectors for the padding frames so they are perfect predictions." is that true? because when the X is 0 but the biases is > 0, the loss will be affected, i think!

Comment: I agree, the biases or even a simple sigmoid would generate non-zero outputs.

Comment: but I have a problem with this statement in the website. Predictions are not zero vectors when padded because you are taking your unscaled logits through softmax layer which means that now they are nonzero. Only targets are zero, so multiplying nonzero scaled logits (i.e. predictions) with zero targets will be zero, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to pad the two logits and labels so that they have the same length. So, if you have the tensors `logits` with the size of `(batch_size, length, vocab_size)` and `labels` with the size of `(batch_size, length)` in which `length` is the size of your sequence. First, you have to pad them to same length:

```py
def _pad_tensors_to_same_length(logits, labels):
    """Pad x and y so that the results have the same length (second dimension)."""
    with tf.name_scope("pad_to_same_length"):
        logits_length = tf.shape(logits)[1]
        labels_length = tf.shape(labels)[1]

        max_length = tf.maximum(logits_length, labels_length)

        logits = tf.pad(logits, [[0, 0], [0, max_length - logits_length], [0, 0]])
        labels = tf.pad(labels, [[0, 0], [0, max_length - labels_length]])
        return logits, labels
```

Then you can do the padded cross entropy:

```py
def padded_cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels, vocab_size):
  """Calculate cross entropy loss while ignoring padding.

  Args:
    logits: Tensor of size [batch_size, length_logits, vocab_size]
    labels: Tensor of size [batch_size, length_labels]
    vocab_size: int size of the vocabulary
  Returns:
    Returns the cross entropy loss 
  """
  with tf.name_scope("loss", values=[logits, labels]):
    logits, labels = _pad_tensors_to_same_length(logits, labels)

    # Calculate cross entropy
    with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy", values=[logits, labels]):
      xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
          logits=logits, labels=targets)

    weights = tf.to_float(tf.not_equal(labels, 0))
    return xentropy * weights
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below takes two tensors with shapes (batch_size,time_steps,vocab_len). computes the mask for zeroing the time steps related to padding. the mask will remove the loss of padding from the categorical cross entropy.

```
# the labels that has 1 as the first element
def mask_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mask_value = np.zeros((vocab_len))
    mask_value[0] = 1
    # find out which timesteps in `y_true` are not the padding character 
    mask = K.equal(y_true, mask_value)
    mask = 1 - K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
    mask = K.sum(mask,axis=2)/2
    # multplying the loss by the mask. the loss for padding will be zero
    loss = tf.keras.layers.multiply([K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), mask])
    return K.sum(loss) / K.sum(mask)
```